# I have almost finished my table format

Tags: tables

Sorry for so many questions, but I am assembling my thesis' table. Thanks to the community's help, I was able to generate the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{6}{l}SS}
  \caption{Amplified Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \hline
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue & qValueRes \\ 
   \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & qValue & qValueRes \\ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
 \hline
  \endlastfoot

1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
3 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
4 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
5 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
6 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
7 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
8 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.73e-13 & 1.10e-07 \\
9 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
10 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\
11 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\
12 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
13 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
14 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
15 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
16 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
17 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
18 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 2.25e-04 & 2.25e-04 \\
19 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\
20 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\
21 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\
22 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\
23 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 1.06e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
24 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\
25 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\
26 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 2.26e-02 & 2.26e-02 \\
27 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
28 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 5.46e-03 & 8.05e-03 \\
29 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
30 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
31 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
32 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
33 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\
34 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\
35 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
36 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
37 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
38 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
39 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
40 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 2.09e-02 & 2.02e-01 \\
41 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 8.33e-02 & 1.48e-01 \\
42 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
43 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
44 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
45 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
46 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
47 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
48 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
49 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
50 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
51 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
52 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
53 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.49e-11 & 8.37e-08 \\
54 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 1.50e-02 & 1.50e-02 \\
55 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
56 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
57 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
58 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 1.52e-03 & 1.63e-02 \\
59 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 3.44e-02 & 1.12e-01 \\
60 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\
61 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\
62 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
63 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 4.36e-02 & 6.39e-02 \\
64 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
65 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
66 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
67 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
68 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
69 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
70 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 1.20e-01 & 1.48e-01 \\
71 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\
72 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\
73 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
74 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
75 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
76 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
77 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
78 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
79 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
80 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 8.05e-03 & 2.76e-02 \\
81 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.98e-08 & 1.98e-08 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why do the two last columns so far apart and part of the "qValue" header is missing? I suspect it's because of siunitx, no? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because  they are non-numerical data in `S`columns. I took the opportunity to fine tune the format of these cells specifying the numbers format, instead of using the default. I added  some vertical padding to each row with the `cellspace` package and the rule commands from `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable, caption, cellspace, booktabs}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation = true }
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\sisetup{table-format =1.2e-2}
\begin{longtable}{ Cr *{6}{l}SS}
  \caption{Amplified Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\\
  \toprule
  & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\
   \midrule
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\\[1ex]
  \toprule
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\
  \midrule
  \endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
 \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot

1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
3 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
4 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
5 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
6 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
7 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
8 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.73e-13 & 1.10e-07 \\
9 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
10 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\
11 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \\
12 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
13 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
14 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
15 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
16 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
17 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
18 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 2.25e-04 & 2.25e-04 \\
19 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\
20 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \\
21 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\
22 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \\
23 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 1.06e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
24 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\
25 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \\
26 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 2.26e-02 & 2.26e-02 \\
27 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
28 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 5.46e-03 & 8.05e-03 \\
29 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
30 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
31 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
32 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
33 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\
34 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \\
35 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
36 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \\
37 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
38 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
39 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
40 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 2.09e-02 & 2.02e-01 \\
41 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 8.33e-02 & 1.48e-01 \\
42 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \\
43 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
44 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
45 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \\
46 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
47 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
48 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
49 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
50 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
51 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
52 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \\
53 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.49e-11 & 8.37e-08 \\
54 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 1.50e-02 & 1.50e-02 \\
55 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
56 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \\
57 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
58 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 1.52e-03 & 1.63e-02 \\
59 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 3.44e-02 & 1.12e-01 \\
60 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\
61 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \\
62 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
63 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 4.36e-02 & 6.39e-02 \\
64 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
65 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
66 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
67 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
68 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
69 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
70 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 1.20e-01 & 1.48e-01 \\
71 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\
72 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \\
73 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \\
74 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
75 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
76 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
77 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \\
78 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \\
79 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \\
80 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 8.05e-03 & 2.76e-02 \\
81 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.98e-08 & 1.98e-08 
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The output is simply gorgeous! Honestly, I am truly grateful that such boards and helpful people exist. I can look at the code and the documentation and learn much better than with the documentation alone. :D

Comment: Always glad to be useful. Personally, I would have aligned also the `p` or `q` letters in the fourth column, and right-aligned the big numbers in the sixth and seventh columns.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. The `siunitx` package considers `qValue` and `qValueRes` to be units. Place them in `{` `}` to fix the problem. I.e. the line in the heading of the table should become: `& Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \\`
2. The second problem is with the `S` class of the columns with your numbers. To fix it, you need to tweak the settings of the `S` class manually like this:

   ```
   \begin{longtable}{ r *{6}{l}S[table-number-alignment = center,table-figures-integer=2,
   table-figures-decimal=2,table-figures-exponent=2]S[table-number-alignment = center,table-figures-integer=2,
   table-figures-decimal=2,table-figures-exponent=2]}
   ```

Full fixed code:
`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{scientific-notation=true}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{longtable}{ r *{6}{l}S[table-number-alignment = center,table-figures-integer=2,
table-figures-decimal=2,table-figures-exponent=2]S[table-number-alignment = center,table-figures-integer=2,
table-figures-decimal=2,table-figures-exponent=2]}
  \caption{Amplified Genes in Claudin-Low Breast Cancer}\label{tab:genes}\
  \hline
  & {Gene} & {Description} & {Cytoband} & {Chr} & {Start} & {End} & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \ 
   \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{Table \ref{tab:genes}, continued}\[1ex]
  \hline
 & Gene & Description & Cytoband & Chr & Start & End & {qValue} & {qValueRes} \ 
  \hline
  \endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on next page)}
  \endfoot
 \hline
  \endlastfoot`

1 & A26B1 & protein expressed in prostate, ovary, testis, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19305252 & 19336667 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \
2 & APOD & apolipoprotein D precursor & 3q29 & chr3 & 196776864 & 196792278 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \
3 & BEST3 & vitelliform macular dystrophy 2-like 3 isoform & 12q15 & chr12 & 68333655 & 68379463 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
4 & BTNL3 & butyrophilin-like 3 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180348506 & 180366333 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \
5 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 long form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258734 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \
6 & BTNL8 & butyrophilin-like 8 short form & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180258764 & 180310512 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \
7 & CCT2 & chaperonin containing TCP1, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68265474 & 68281624 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
8 & CDC73 & parafibromin & 1q31.2 & chr1 & 191357783 & 191487679 & 4.73e-13 & 1.10e-07 \
9 & CNOT2 & CCR4-NOT transcription complex, subunit 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68923043 & 69035040 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
10 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform MB-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18309308 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \
11 & COMT & catechol-O-methyltransferase isoform S-COMT & 22q11.21 & chr22 & 18330069 & 18336530 & 6.39e-02 & 1.43e-01 \
12 & CORO7 & coronin 7 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4344543 & 4406640 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \
13 & CPM & carboxypeptidase M precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 67531222 & 67613246 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
14 & CPSF6 & cleavage and polyadenylation specific factor 6, & 12q15 & chr12 & 67919583 & 67954405 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
15 & DDT & D-dopachrome tautomerase & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22643553 & 22646680 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \
16 & DDTL & D-dopachrome tautomerase-like & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22639025 & 22644748 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \
17 & DNAJA3 & DnaJ (Hsp40) homolog, subfamily A, member 3 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4415882 & 4446776 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \
18 & DOK6 & docking protein 6 & 18q22.2 & chr18 & 65219270 & 65660359 & 2.25e-04 & 2.25e-04 \
19 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform a & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219982084 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \
20 & DUSP10 & dual specificity phosphatase 10 isoform b & 1q41 & chr1 & 219941388 & 219977425 & 2.66e-06 & 4.80e-03 \
21 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform b & 17q12 & chr17 & 35097918 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \
22 & ERBB2 & erbB-2 isoform a & 17q12 & chr17 & 35109779 & 35138441 & 3.67e-18 & 1.47e-12 \
23 & ERG & v-ets erythroblastosis virus E26 oncogene like & 21q22.2 & chr21 & 38675670 & 38955488 & 1.06e-02 & 8.62e-02 \
24 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 1 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713254 & 37734477 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \
25 & ERLIN2 & ER lipid raft associated 2 isoform 2 & 8p12 & chr8 & 37713356 & 37723229 & 4.23e-21 & 4.23e-21 \
26 & FLJ20433 & hypothetical protein LOC54932 & 9q34.3 & chr9 & 139321168 & 139437535 & 2.26e-02 & 2.26e-02 \
27 & FLJ39743 & hypothetical protein LOC283777 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 96797913 & 96875134 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \
28 & FLT3 & fms-related tyrosine kinase 3 & 13q12.2 & chr13 & 27475410 & 27572729 & 5.46e-03 & 8.05e-03 \
29 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 2 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \
30 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 1 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \
31 & FOXP4 & forkhead box P4 isoform 3 & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41622141 & 41678100 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \
32 & FRS2 & fibroblast growth factor receptor substrate 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68150395 & 68259829 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
33 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform a & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \
34 & GAB1 & GRB2-associated binding protein 1 isoform b & 4q31.21 & chr4 & 144477499 & 144610729 & 1.17e-03 & 3.20e-02 \
35 & GSTT2 & glutathione S-transferase theta 2 & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633393 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \
36 & GSTT2B & glutathione S-transferase theta 2B & 22q11.23 & chr22 & 22629600 & 22633368 & 4.91e-02 & 6.61e-01 \
37 & hsa-mir-570 & hsa-mir-570 & 3q29 & chr3 & 196911451 & 196911548 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \
38 & IGF1R & insulin-like growth factor 1 receptor precursor & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97010283 & 97325282 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \
39 & KCNMB4 & calcium-activated potassium channel beta 4 & 12q15 & chr12 & 69046328 & 69111245 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
40 & KIT & v-kit Hardy-Zuckerman 4 feline sarcoma viral & 4q12 & chr4 & 55218851 & 55301638 & 2.09e-02 & 2.02e-01 \
41 & LANCL2 & LanC lantibiotic synthetase component C-like 2 & 7p11.2 & chr7 & 55400634 & 55468929 & 8.33e-02 & 1.48e-01 \
42 & LOC145814 & hypothetical protein LOC145814 & 15q26.3 & chr15 & 97329031 & 97366314 & 7.17e-02 & 8.62e-02 \
43 & LOC283755 & hypothetical protein LOC283755 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 18848557 & 18971443 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \
44 & LOC283767 & hypothetical protein LOC283767 & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 20287609 & 20296164 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \
45 & LOC646227 & hypothetical protein LOC646227 & 5q35.3 & chr5 & 180341823 & 180345858 & 1.54e-01 & 1.54e-01 \
46 & LOC650137 & seven transmembrane helix receptor & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19915065 & 19915749 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \
47 & LRRC10 & leucine rich repeat containing 10 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68288611 & 68291209 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
48 & LYZ & lysozyme precursor & 12q15 & chr12 & 68028400 & 68034280 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
49 & Magmas & mitochondria-associated granulocyte macrophage & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4330252 & 4341301 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \
50 & MDFI & MyoD family inhibitor & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41714230 & 41729959 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \
51 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform S & 3q29 & chr3 & 196936768 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \
52 & MUC20 & mucin 20 isoform L & 3q29 & chr3 & 196933423 & 196950211 & 1.06e-06 & 1.41e-03 \
53 & NACA2 & nascent-polypeptide-associated complex alpha & 17q23.2 & chr17 & 57022571 & 57023345 & 2.49e-11 & 8.37e-08 \
54 & OR11H12 & olfactory receptor, family 11, subfamily H, & 14q11.1 & chr14 & 18447593 & 18448574 & 1.50e-02 & 1.50e-02 \
55 & OR4M2 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily M, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19869939 & 19870881 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \
56 & OR4N4 & olfactory receptor, family 4, subfamily N, & 15q11.2 & chr15 & 19883836 & 19884787 & 9.37e-03 & 2.18e-02 \
57 & PGC & progastricsin (pepsinogen C) & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41812429 & 41823099 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \
58 & PIK3CA & phosphoinositide-3-kinase, catalytic, alpha & 3q26.32 & chr3 & 180349004 & 180435191 & 1.52e-03 & 1.63e-02 \
59 & PLXNC1 & plexin C1 & 12q22 & chr12 & 93066629 & 93223356 & 3.44e-02 & 1.12e-01 \
60 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform b & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \
61 & PTK2 & PTK2 protein tyrosine kinase 2 isoform a & 8q24.3 & chr8 & 141737682 & 142080514 & 5.14e-21 & 5.81e-11 \
62 & PTPRB & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, B & 12q15 & chr12 & 69196898 & 69317486 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
63 & PTPRD & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, D & 9p23 & chr9 & 8304245 & 10602509 & 4.36e-02 & 6.39e-02 \
64 & PTPRR & protein tyrosine phosphatase, receptor type, R & 12q15 & chr12 & 69318128 & 69600851 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
65 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform A & 12q15 & chr12 & 68459020 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
66 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
67 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 1 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68418897 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
68 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform beta 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
69 & RAB3IP & RAB3A interacting protein isoform alpha 2 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68419446 & 68503251 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
70 & RB1 & retinoblastoma 1 & 13q14.2 & chr13 & 47775883 & 47954027 & 1.20e-01 & 1.48e-01 \
71 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform c & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42942958 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \
72 & RET & ret proto-oncogene isoform a & 10q11.21 & chr10 & 42892522 & 42945803 & 3.83e-03 & 5.70e-02 \
73 & TFEB & transcription factor EB & 6p21.1 & chr6 & 41759693 & 41810776 & 2.26e-02 & 2.24e-01 \
74 & TMPRSS11E & transmembrane protease, serine 11E & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \
75 & TMPRSS11E2 & transmembrane protease, serine 11E2 & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 68995761 & 69045917 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \
76 & UGT2B15 & UDP glycosyltransferase 2 family, polypeptide & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69194909 & 69218969 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \
77 & UGT2B17 & UDP glucuronosyltransferase 2 family, & 4q13.2 & chr4 & 69085497 & 69116840 & 7.51e-06 & 1.55e-04 \
78 & VASN & slit-like 2 & 16p13.3 & chr16 & 4361849 & 4373530 & 6.14e-03 & 9.79e-03 \
79 & YEATS4 & glioma-amplified sequence-41 & 12q15 & chr12 & 68039798 & 68070843 & 2.56e-02 & 5.28e-02 \
80 & ZDHHC11 & zinc finger, DHHC-type containing 11 & 5p15.33 & chr5 & 848721 & 904101 & 8.05e-03 & 2.76e-02 \
81 & ZNF709 & zinc finger protein 709 & 19p13.2 & chr19 & 12435742 & 12456632 & 1.98e-08 & 1.98e-08 \
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you very very much! So qValue and qValueRes are "built-in" siunitx? I have learned a great deal! :D

Comment: I don't think they are built-in, but they are in the `S` column which assumes numbers and units to be in it.